# Achieving Seamless User Authentication and Registration in a Multitenant Laravel/Next.js App

Tags: laravel, authentication, next.js, single-sign-on, multi-tenant

I'm currently exploring a solution to enable user authentication in a multitenant application without any visible user interactions. Specifically, I'm looking to seamlessly log in or register users into my helpdesk app when they are already logged in on the tenant website.

Here's the context: I've developed a helpdesk ticketing application that utilizes Laravel as the backend and Next.js as the frontend. The authentication process is managed by Sanctum (Airlock) for communication between the frontend and backend.

In this multitenant setup, each tenant within the helpdesk application can have its unique domain. They are distinguished based on their URL through the Stancl/Tenancy Package. So, Tenants have the option to point a subdomain (e.g., 'crm.tenant1.com') to the helpdesk frontend.

The challenge arises when a user visits this subdomain. They are required to log in or register again within the helpdesk app, despite being already logged in on the tenant website.

My objective is to make this login or registration process transparent to the user. If a user is already logged in on the tenant website, they should automatically be logged into the tenant when they access 'crm.tenant1.com'. If it's their initial visit, and the user does not exist in the helpdesk database, it should request their user data from 'tenant1.com', proceed with user registration, and log them in without any noticeable interruption.

I want the user experience to resemble a seamless transition to another page within 'tenant1.com' when they navigate to 'crm.tenant1.com'.

Could you provide insights and guidance on how to achieve this objective? Is this feasible with Sanctum, or do I need to consider alternative packages? Additionally, any recommended best practices for implementing this seamless authentication and registration process would be greatly appreciated. Your expertise would be of immense help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not control the tenant domain, your best bet is to implement an SSO solution like [SAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language) or [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) where your customer does the authorization/authentication and you support the protocol on your side.

This of course means, that your tenants need to have an authentication provider, while you need to implement a client on your side. Since these are standardized protocols, it is easy for both sides to find libraries or off the shelve servers that implement them.